# одна страница на сайте через http

Tags: nginx, http, ssl, https

Есть VPS, на нем домен и SSL сертификат через ISP менеджер. Сайт открывается через https, при вводе http идет переадресация на https. Как сделать одну страницу сайта на http (http://supersite.ru/page1), остальные на https?

NGNIX:

```
#user 'supersite' virtual host 'supersite.ru' configuration file
server {
    server_name supersite.ru www.supersite.ru;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/supersite/data/www/supersite.ru;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/supersite.ru.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/supersite.ru.error.log notice;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location / {
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        access_log off ;
    }
    ssi on;
    listen 178.208.75.143:80;
    listen 178.208.81.14:80;
}
server {
    server_name supersite.ru www.supersite.ru;
    charset UTF-8;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    index index.php;
    root $root_path;
    set $root_path /var/www/supersite/data/www/supersite.ru;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/supersite.ru.access.log ;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/supersite.ru.error.log notice;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    location / {
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @fallback;
        }
        location / {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @fallback;
        }
    }
    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        access_log off ;
    }
    ssi on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";
    listen 178.208.75.143:443;
    listen 178.208.81.14:443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/supersite/supersite.crtca";
    ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/supersite/supersite.key";
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!EXP:!LOW:!SEED:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!PSK:!SRP:!SSLv2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Comment: Если доя браузера, то никак. У вас стоит заголовок STS

Comment: С другой стороны я не вижу никакого редиректа на https

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы сайт весь открывался и с http и c https?

Comment: Вот и я не вижу, а он есть

Comment: Как вы проверяли? Что говорит `curl -I http://supersite.ru`

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 10:33:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Ну вот, открывается же

Comment: Так в браузере открывается сразу https!

Comment: `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";` — вы сами застали браузер делать так.

Answer (score 1):

Разделить обработку на 2 сервера, сделав перенаправление ненужных адресов с https на http и не использовать Strict-Transport-Security, чтобы браузер принудительно не перенаправлял все запросы на https-сервер.
[Здесь пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-https-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-url-nginx/597930#597930).