# Как отключить https для определенных URL (nginx)?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

Надо отключить https для url таких видов:

```
/mailview?.....
/msd?....
/separator?....
```

Чтобы они работали по http. Сейчас общей склейки нет работает по http и https надо врубить https для всего сайта кроме 3х url:

```
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443 ssl http2;
```

Если без Strict-Transport-Security сделать так:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Возможно ли как то сюда подсунуть эти 3 урл чтобы это правило не действовало?
В интеренете гуглил час ничего подобного нет нигде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разделить обработку на 2 сервера, сделав перенаправление ненужных адресов с https на http, например, так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    if ($uri !~* ^/(mailview|msd|separator) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com;
    rewrite ^/(mailview|msd|separator) http://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Как Вы правильно написали, Strict-Transport-Security не использовать, чтобы браузер принудительно не перенаправлял все запросы на https-сервер.